# Cannot get RSS feed content with Rome

Tags: java, rss, rome

I'm trying to read the content of an RSS feed using Rome 1.7.4. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        URL feedURL = new URL("http://feeds.feedburner.com/consumeraffairs/SXJd");

        SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
        SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(feedURL));

        System.out.println("Feed Title: " + feed.getTitle());

        for (SyndEntry entry : feed.getEntries()){
            System.out.println("Entry Title: " + entry.getTitle());
            System.out.println("URL: " + entry.getUri());
            for (SyndContent content : entry.getContents()){
                System.out.println("Content: " + content.getValue());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the content of the feed, but it never enters the for content loop. Inspection of the variables says that content = null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are no content tags used in your feed. Try `entry.getDescription().getValue()` to get feed's text content.